# No module named 'pyopengv' found

Tags: python, linux, cmake

I'm using Ubunutu LTS 18.04, and trying to install OpenGV module for python3.
I've cloned and built OpenGV from its documentation. I sat the flags for  python 3. I linked pyopengv.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so in folder /usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/.
And still, it doesn't import pyopengv.
I don't get what is wrong.
I will specify what I made in commands...

`git clone https://github.com/laurentkneip/opengv`

`cd opengv`

`mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make`

`git submodule update --init --recursive`

`cmake .. -DBUILD_PYTHON=ON -DPYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION=3.6 -DPYTHON_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages`

`cd /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/`

`ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyopengv.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

And finally I'm in opengv/python trying this
`python3 tests.py`
but still get the error of "No module 'pyopengv' found.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which python are you using, 3.6 or 3.7? Also, doesn't `ln -s` take *two* arguments?

Comment: I don't know about all `ln` implementations, but on Ubuntu 18.04 it looks like `ln -s` will default the second argument to `./`

Comment: As for ln, it's as shay said. I can write ```.``` in the end or not.
As for the python version, I've actually noticed something just a few minutes ago. I'm supposedly using 3.6 .. but then I've anaconda and I think it's using 3.7, and it installs modules for 3.7. I don't know. I think there's something messed up with pip and anaconda and different versions of python. How can I fix it? I'm thinking of reinstalling it all a fresh start, but deleting py3.6 and pip completely.

Answer (score 0):

> No module named 'pyopengv' found

`python3 tests.py` will look for pyopengv in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`

So either do `cmake -DBUILD_PYTHON=ON -DPYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION=3.6 -DPYTHON_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ ..` or make a symlink to the desired location.

Ubuntu 18.04 with `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyopengv.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` ... testing

```
$ python3 tests.py 
Testing relative pose
Done testing relative pose
Testing relative pose ransac
Done testing relative pose ransac
Testing relative pose ransac rotation only
Done testing relative pose ransac rotation only
Testing triangulation
Done testing triangulation
```

---

Edit, Mar 05 2020

> Ubuntu 18.04, the complete build sequence :
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/laurentkneip/opengv.git
> cd opengv/
> git submodule update --init --recursive
> mkdir build && cd build/ 
> cmake -DBUILD_PYTHON=ON -DPYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION=3.6 -DPYTHON_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ ..
> make && sudo make install
> ```
>
> Check module location :
>
> ```
> find /usr/lib/ -name pyopengv.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
>
> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyopengv.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
> ```

Note : A check with "Other Linux OS" → Usable module location was /usr/lib64/python**3.6/site**-packages

Comment: I tried the ```cmake -DBUILD_PYTHON=ON -DPYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION=3.6 -DPYTHON_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ .. ``` and then running python3 tests.py and still same thing. No module named 'pyopengv'.

Comment: Could you please check my comment above in the questions itself? If it can show anything useful...

Comment: The module was deleted ... and I made a second 'make install' : same result. ( Please see the edited answer.)

Comment: I'm trying it now. Sorry I reply late. BTW though, I changed Python Version in the command from 3. to 3.7 because that's the version recognized when I use command ```python -V```

Comment: Same output unfortunately. :(